# New RMSD after a new variable is introduced?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

So I have 5 variables which have the RMSD equal to let's say 100.
If a sixth variable is introduced which is equal to the mean of the first 5 variables then how can I calculate the new RMSD?

Comment: You should spell out what is RMSD (as an edit, not as a comment)